# How to center a text and position to right using css and html

Tags: html, css

I have a div(content) class where text 1 should be centered and text 2 should be located to right.
I tried using position:absolute but it text 2 gets out of the div.

```
       <div style="text-align: center;">              
          <div>
            <h3 class="content-title">Text1 </h3>              
          </div>
          <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:80px;">Text 2</div>
        </div>
```

Below is an image that I would like to get.

[Click here to see the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbymN.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `position:relative;` to main div and remove `top:80px;` from the `text-2`

```html
<div style="text-align: center; position: relative;">              
  <div>
    <h3 class="content-title">Text1 </h3>              
  </div>
  <div style="position:absolute; right:20px; top:0px;">Text 2</div>
</div>
```